# NoSuchMethodError on certain OS versions

Tags: java, android, nosuchmethoderror

I’m not sure why I’m getting this error only on certain Android versions (below 5.0).

I’m calling:

```
myImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image, null));
```

Because of this I’m getting a `NoSuchMethodError`.
What to do?

Comment: you can simple add your context in front of getDrawable()
YOURCONTEXT.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image, null)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this

```
myImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.image));
```

Instead of this

```
myImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image, null));
```

**EDIT**

when you use `setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image, null));` this it will shows below error

[image]

**NOTE** `setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image, null));` this method is  added in API level 21

You can read more about [**ContextCompat**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html)

Comment: Ok I get it! Thanks

Comment: @Someday happy to help you

Answer (score 3):

> Use [ContextCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html), it's helper class for accessing features in
>   [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

Using this class you can easily access the following resources,

- ImageDrawable
- String
- Colour
- ColorStateList
- CodeCacheDir

And many more...

**Try by following way,**

```
myImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.image));
```

Answer (score 1):

@Prem answer is the right one. Just adding this to provide you with a tip.

In Android documentation there is an indication of which API level included each method. For example, [the one you're using](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme)) was introduced in Android 5.0 (API level 21).

[image: API documentation example]

Answer (score 1):

You are calling
`getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image, null)` method which is added in API level 21

check [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme))

If you are using second parameter (theme)  as a null

So try to use

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
```

You can use following code for the same

```
myImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image));
```